# No Route found using mapbox map matching API but Google maps is displaying the route between source and destination

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

For the following source and destination, Mapbox Map Matching API is not giving any route in response. But Google Maps is instead showing the route.

Source - 41.903183,-87.630716
Destination - 41.900127,-87.621664

Mapbox Map Matching Request

https://api.mapbox.com/matching/v5/mapbox/walking/-87.630716,41.903183;-87.621664,41.900127?access_token="..."&geometries=polyline6&steps=true&overview=full&banner_instructions=true&voice_instructions=true&waypoints=0%3B1

Mapbox Map Matching Response

{
    "code": "NoMatch",
    "message": "No matching found",
    "matchings": []
}

Why Mapbox is not giving any route? It would be great if anybody can explain it in detail.

Another example, for which mapbox is not giving route is:

Source - 41.90332,-87.630696
Destination - 41.900127,-87.621664

Answer (score 1):

Taking both permutations of your coordinates into account, as Google is using (lat,lng) and Mapbox is using (lng,lat):

**(lat,lng)**: both your positions are in the ocean approximately 1300km off the coast of Chile.

**(lng, lat)**: both your positions are on Antartica, where there are no roads.

Why do you think there should be a response?

Comment: It's just the coordinate format differentiation. If there is a coordinate A[lat1, lng1], then
Google uses - A[lat1, lng1]
Mapbox uses - A[lng1, lat1]
The coordinate hasn't changed. If what you mean is true, then mapbox wouldn't have worked at all for rest of the coordinates